# Showing An Operator is Unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T = T^*$ be operators and $\lVert T\rVert \leq 1$. Define an operator $U := T + i(I - T^2)^{1/2}$. Then *U* is a unitary operator.

I know that I need to show that $U^*U = UU^* = I$. So I must find the adjoint of *U*. I know that $(Ux|y) = (x|U^*y)$. However, I am not sure what $(Ux|y)$ looks like. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: HINT: $(A+B)^\ast=A^\ast+B^\ast$ and $(zA)^\ast=\overline{z}A^\ast$. Also, $(I-T^2)^{1/2}$ is self-adjoint. Use this to compute $U^\ast$.

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure of the first fact.

Comment: When in doubt, prove it. You have $$\langle (A+B)x|y\rangle = \langle Ax|y\rangle +\langle Bx|y\rangle = \langle x|A^\star y\rangle + \langle x|B^\star y\rangle= \langle x|(A^\star + B^\star)y\rangle.$$ But on the other hand, $$\langle (A+B)x|y\rangle = \langle x|(A+B)^\star y\rangle , $$ so comparing the two equations we see that $(A+B)^\star=A^\star + B^\star$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial fact you need to know is that $T$ commutes with $(I-T^{2})^{1/2}$. Once you know this you can write $UU^{*}=(T+i(I-T^{2})^{1/2})(T-i(I-T^{2})^{1/2})=T^{2}+(I-T^{2})=I$. Similarly, $U^{*}U=I$.

Comment: Thank you. I was also forgetting the key fact that T commutes with $(I - T^2)^{1/2}$.